# Edge Download Bar

Tags: microsoft-edge

What setting controls if the edge download bar is showing at the bottom of the page or on the right?

My Win11 edge is showing it on the right and I find that annoying. I couldn't find a setting controlling that, so imagine my surprise after installing windows server and seeing the downloads show at the bottom of the window like on google chrome.

Comment: A surprisingly large number of UI elements can be simply dragged with the mouse. Have you tried that?

Comment: I downloaded something today and the dialogue window is top right where it has always been for me.

Comment: I tried dragging it but no, it stays on the right. On this Windows 2022 server however it is on the bottom just like Chrome.